# how do i load modules and files in the intern config module?

Tags: intern

I am assuming the default loader is dojo for configs, https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern. How to do I load other modules or files in the config module? I would like to load JSON file and a node module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct -- a Dojo loader is used to load the config. However, it's not the standard Dojo loader, it may not always behave the same or provide the same modules, and it's not technically part of Intern's API. So in general, it's better to provide your own copies of the things you need rather than relying on Intern's Dojo.

Given that caveat...Intern's Dojo does include both `dojo/node` and `dojo/text`, so you can do something like:

```
define([ 'intern/dojo/node!module', 'intern/dojo/text!jsonFile' ], function (mod, data) {
    var config = {
        ...
    };
    return config;
});
```

**Note:** Loading a node module in your config will prevent your tests from running in a browser. You'll only be able to run them with the Node.js client (`intern-client`).

Comment: Thanks. I will create the config as part of a build step to remove the node dependency. I am in the process of replacing [grunt-castle](https://github.com/walmartlabs/grunt-castle) with intern for testing [lazo](https://github.com/walmartlabs/lazojs/) and lazo applications. I wrote grunt-castle as an attempt to encapsulate a bunch of boilerplate code for testing client-server code until a colleague introduced me to intern. Good stuff. Thanks for sharing it.